# Рестарт подлючения к rabbitmq в golang

Tags: golang, rabbitmq

Я хочу проверить механизм рестарта соединения с сервером `rabbitmq`. 
На написал небольшой скрипт для теста.
http://play.golang.org/p/l3ZWzG0Qqb
Но это не работает.

На шаге 10 я закрываю канал и соединение. И открываю их заново. И заново создаю `chan amqp.Confirmation` (num :75) . И продолжаю цикл.
Но после этого из канала `confirms` ничего не приходит.

UPD:
Выкладываю код и тут.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/streadway/amqp"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"
)

const SERVER = "amqp://user:pass@localhost:5672/"
const EXCHANGE_NAME = "publisher.test.1"
const EXCHANGE_TYPE = "direct"
const ROUTING_KEY = "publisher.test"

var Connection *amqp.Connection
var Channel *amqp.Channel

func setup(url string) (*amqp.Connection, *amqp.Channel, error) {
    conn, err := amqp.Dial(url)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }

    ch, err := conn.Channel()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }

    return conn, ch, nil
}

func main() {
    url := SERVER

    Connection, Channel, err := setup(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("err publisher setup:", err)
        return
    }

    confirms := Channel.NotifyPublish(make(chan amqp.Confirmation, 1))
    if err := Channel.Confirm(false); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("confirm.select destination: %s", err)
    }

    for i := 1; i <= 3000000; i++ {
        log.Println(i)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("err consume:", err)
            return
        }

        if err := Channel.Publish(EXCHANGE_NAME, ROUTING_KEY, false, false, amqp.Publishing{
            Body: []byte(fmt.Sprintf("%d", i)),
        }); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("err publish:", err)
            log.Printf("%+v", err)
            os.Exit(1)
            return
        }

        // only ack the source delivery when the destination acks the publishing
        confirmed := <-confirms
        if confirmed.Ack {
            log.Printf("confirmed delivery with delivery tag: %d", confirmed.DeliveryTag)
        } else {
            log.Printf("failed delivery of delivery tag: %d", confirmed.DeliveryTag)
            // TODO. Reconnect will be here
        }

        if i == 10 {
            Channel.Close()
            Connection.Close()
            while := true
            for while {
                log.Println("while")
                time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
                Connection, Channel, err = setup(url)
                if err == nil {
                    while = false
                    confirms = Channel.NotifyPublish(make(chan amqp.Confirmation, 1))
                    log.Printf("%+v", confirms)
                }
            }
        }
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 300)
    }

    os.Exit(1)
}
```

Comment: Выложи код здесь.

Comment: Что-то я не вижу QueueDeclare и ExchangeDeclare.

Comment: Да. Тут нет декларирования queue и exchange, так как это не влияет на работу кода. Сообщения пушаться и просто по exchangeName и routingKey.
Вопрос - как сделатать реконнект. В документации какой-то невразумительный пример. Который не используют chan confirmation. А без этого chan'а exchange не проверяет, действительно ли он запушил сообщение. И продолжает пушить, даже если сеть оборвать. (проверено на опытах)

Comment: Не надо вешать всякие `[РЕШЕНО]` и аналоги, это всё костыли. У нас это обеспечивается механизмом "галочек" на ответах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решено.

При повторном открытии канала нотификаций надо было также вызвать метод `Channel.Confirm(false)`

```
confirms := Channel.NotifyPublish(make(chan amqp.Confirmation, 1))
if err := Channel.Confirm(false); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("confirm.select destination: %s", err)
}
```